# Python: appending a dataframe with user inputted strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

So I am currently working on some code and what I have so far is

```
numbers=int(raw_input('Enter number of classes you are taking:))
#loop for info for each class
for x in range(numbers):
    data = str(raw_input(Enter class name,teacher,credit hours))
    df={'class name':data[0],'teacher':data[1],'credit hours':data[2]}
    frame=frame.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

I can't seem to get the data frame to print the 1st value of the user inputted string, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frame = []
numbers=int(raw_input('Enter number of classes you are taking:'))
#loop for info for each class
for x in range(numbers):
   data = str(raw_input('Enter classname,teacher,credithours:')).split(',')
   # print(data) # out => [name,teacher,credit hours] 
   df={'class name':data[0],'teacher':data[1],'credit hours':data[2]}
   frame=frame.append(df)
   print(frame)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting a 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'